# Error in Magento: Argument 2 passed to Magento\Framework\Pricing\Price\Pool::__construct() [...]

Tags: php, magento2

I do not want to change the core files. and I don't understand why this happened its work perfect before.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Magento\Framework\Pricing\Price\Pool::__construct() 
must implement interface , array given, called in 
    E:\xamp70\htdocs\itemart\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php 
on line 111 and defined in 
    E:\xamp70\htdocs\itemart\vendor\magento\framework\Pricing\Price\Pool.php:25 

Stack trace: 

#0 E:\xamp70\htdocs\itemart\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php(111): 
   Magento\Framework\Pricing\Price\Pool->__construct(Array, Array) 

#1 E:\xamp70\htdocs\itemart\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php(66): 
   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Framewo...', Array) 

#2 E:\xamp70\htdocs\itemart\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager.php(70): 
   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Downloa...')

#3 E:\xamp70\htdocs\itemart\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php(144): 
   Magento\Framework\ObjectMa in E:\xamp70\htdocs\itemart\vendor\magento\framework\Pricing\Price\Pool.php on line 25
```

Answer (score 0):

Magento generates classes along with their constructors, and the generated classes extends the base class to call plugins. Well, usually the pre-generated classes are out of date and due to that you are getting this error `Argument 2 passed to Magento\Framework\Pricing\Price\Pool::__construct()`.

So what you could do to fix this issue by running the below commands from the root directory of Magento from the terminal:

```
/* removing the old generated source files */
rm -rf var/di var/generation

/* generate new source files */
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Comment: @thanks adeel i fix this but  /js/theme.js' b   | Magento_Theme/js/responsive.js' because its MIME type  type issue comes in console

Comment: @anumali did you manage to fix this MIME issue? if not, then this issue can be occurred due to the .htaccess file in `pub/static` folder. Perhaps, the file has been deleted from the folder, so adding `.htaccess` in the pub/static directory will resolve this issue

Comment: magento sucks i leave that magento

Comment: lol, well in my opinion Magento is well maintained and structured, and if you're having issues then you could ask on SO or [Magento Stackexchange](https://magento.stackexchange.com) and you know what is the best part of Magento.. there is always a solution to the problem :)

Comment: @Adeel Same problem here https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/318269/57334 How to solve this error?